# Dataset to XMLDocument repeats three times

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I am trying to output the values from a dataset to an xml document using System.Xml.Linq, however the values for each element are repeated three times in each dataset element instead of there being only one

To iterate through the dataset and convert the xml I am using this code

```
Dim variableList As New List(Of String)()
    Dim rowList As New List(Of String)()


    For Each column As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
        variableList.Add(column.ColumnName)

        Dim variables As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "variables").FirstOrDefault
        Dim variable As XElement = <variable varName=<%= column.ColumnName %> trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;"></variable>
        variables.Add(variable)


        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            rowList.Add(dr.Item(column))

            Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").FirstOrDefault()
            Dim newEle As XElement = <<%= column.ColumnName %>><p><%= dr.Item(column) %></p></>
            sampleDataSets.Add(newEle)
        Next
    Next


    For Each dataRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim strDatasheet As String = dataRow("Dataset").ToString


        Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_v As XNamespace = sampleDataSets.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("v")

        Dim dataSetName As XAttribute = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("dataSetName")
        dataSetName.SetValue(strDatasheet)

        Dim dataset As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Dataset").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns_dataset As XNamespace = dataset.Name.Namespace

        sampleDataSets.AddAfterSelf(sampleDataSets)

        Dim number As Integer
        number += 1
        If number = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count Then
            sampleDataSets.Remove()
            dataSetName.Remove()
        End If
    Next
```

This outputs the following XMLDocument

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd"[
      <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    ]>
    <svg>
      <variableSets xmlns="ns_vars;">
        <variableSet varSetName="binding1" locked="none">
          <variables>
            <variable varName="Dataset" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Name" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Rev" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Desc" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Marketing" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Project" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="DPN" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
          </variables>
          <v:sampleDataSets xmlns:v="http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai">
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F A00_(London).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6</p>
              </Name>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>E7270 </p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15011</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15001</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12</p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 1234</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 5345</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 35345</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai">
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F A00_(London).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6</p>
              </Name>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15021</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>L15011</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p> 15001</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N:456456</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 4564</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 456</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="0C11F A00_(London).ai">
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>00C11F A00_(London).ai</p>
              </Dataset>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F</p>
              </Name>
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6</p>
              </Name>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15021</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15011</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p>15001</p>
              </Marketing>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p>Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p> Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 565465</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 6456</p>
              </DPN>
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 4564</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
          </v:sampleDataSets>
        </variableSet>
      </variableSets>
    </svg>
```

The code seems to be iterating three times before writing the next element to the xml document, would anyone be able to offer any advice on where I am going wrong, the document should look like the following format.

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd"[
      <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
      <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    ]>
    <svg>
      <variableSets xmlns="ns_vars;">
        <variableSet varSetName="binding1" locked="none">
          <variables>
            <variable varName="Dataset" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Name" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Rev" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Desc" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Marketing" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="Project" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
            <variable varName="DPN" trait="textcontent" category="ns_flows;" xmlns=""></variable>
          </variables>
          <v:sampleDataSets xmlns:v="http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai">
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH A00_(Glasgow).ai</p>
              </Dataset>          
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>0FFHH</p>
              </Name>          
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>          
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc> 
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p> E7270 </p>
              </Marketing>          
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p> Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>          
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N:3424</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName=">07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai">          
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6 A00_(Munster).ai</p>
              </Dataset>          
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6</p>
              </Name>         
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>          
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL</p>
              </Desc>          
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p> E7270 </p>
              </Marketing>         
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p> Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>          
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N: 2167</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>
            <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="0C11F A00_(London).ai">          
              <Dataset xmlns="">
                <p>0C11F A00_(London).ai</p>
              </Dataset>          
              <Name xmlns="">
                <p>07FV6</p>
              </Name>         
              <Rev xmlns="">
                <p>A00</p>
              </Rev>          
              <Desc xmlns="">
                <p>ESPL,</p>
              </Desc>          
              <Marketing xmlns="">
                <p> E7270 </p>
              </Marketing>         
              <Project xmlns="">
                <p> Creek 12 </p>
              </Project>          
              <DPN xmlns="">
                <p>DP/N:65756</p>
              </DPN>
            </v:sampleDataSet>                
        </variableSet>
      </variableSets>
    </svg>
```

**Updated** 
Jdweng's answer was correct, I show the correct code below to iterate through the data row only once.

```
For Each dataRow As DataRow In result.Tables(0).Rows
        If Not dataRow Is Nothing Then

            Dim strDatasheet As String = dataRow(variableList.Item(0)).ToString

            Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").LastOrDefault
            Dim dataSetName As XAttribute = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").LastOrDefault.Attribute("dataSetName")
            dataSetName.SetValue(strDatasheet)

            sampleDataSets.AddAfterSelf(sampleDataSets)

            For Each item In variableList
                Dim ns_v1 As XNamespace = sampleDataSets.GetDefaultNamespace()
                Dim itemElement As XElement = New XElement(ns_v1 + item)
                Dim dataEle As XElement = New XElement(<p><%= dataRow(item).ToString %></p>)
                sampleDataSets.Add(itemElement)
                itemElement.Add(dataEle)


                For Each node As XElement In sampleDataSets.Descendants()
                    If node.Name.NamespaceName = "" Then
                        node.Attributes("xmlns").Remove()
                        node.Name = node.Parent.Name.[Namespace] + node.Name.LocalName
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Its very tricky to determine a cause without having the dataset, as I cannot reproduce the problem.  If you can simplify the example, and provide a recreatable problem, I would be keen to help.

Comment: Simple.  When you iterate through columns to get the column names only do it for row 0.  You are iterating through each row so the column names are duplicating 3x because you have three rows.

Comment: Thanks  jdweng that fixed the issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to iterate over the data rows only once instead of three times.
below I show the code.

```
For Each dataRow As DataRow In result.Tables(0).Rows
    If Not dataRow Is Nothing Then

        Dim strDatasheet As String = dataRow(variableList.Item(0)).ToString

        Dim sampleDataSets As XElement = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").LastOrDefault
        Dim dataSetName As XAttribute = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "sampleDataSet").LastOrDefault.Attribute("dataSetName")
        dataSetName.SetValue(strDatasheet)

        sampleDataSets.AddAfterSelf(sampleDataSets)

        For Each item In variableList
            Dim ns_v1 As XNamespace = sampleDataSets.GetDefaultNamespace()
            Dim itemElement As XElement = New XElement(ns_v1 + item)
            Dim dataEle As XElement = New XElement(<p><%= dataRow(item).ToString %></p>)
            sampleDataSets.Add(itemElement)
            itemElement.Add(dataEle)


            For Each node As XElement In sampleDataSets.Descendants()
                If node.Name.NamespaceName = "" Then
                    node.Attributes("xmlns").Remove()
                    node.Name = node.Parent.Name.[Namespace] + node.Name.LocalName
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```